# Is there a way to find tags in BeautifulSoup that do not contain a specific class?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a table on a page that has classes on each row. There are some classes that signify that the event has yet to take place and I want to avoid these. The table is similar to this:

```
<tr class="TRow1 TFuture">
<tr class="TRow2 TFuture">
<tr class="TRow1 TFuture">
<tr class="TRow2 TPresent">
<tr class="TRow1 TPast">
<tr class="TRow2">
```

All I seem to be able to find is how to select a class that I want. Is there any way to select everything except for a class I *don't* want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `:not` css selector:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
s = """ 
<tr class="TRow1 TFuture"></tr>
<tr class="TRow2 TFuture"></tr>
<tr class="TRow1 TFuture"></tr>
<tr class="TRow2 TPresent"></tr>
<tr class="TRow1 TPast"></tr>
<tr class="TRow2"></tr>
"""    
tr = soup(s, 'html.parser').select('tr:not(.TFuture)')
```

Output:

```
[<tr class="TRow2 TPresent"></tr>, <tr class="TRow1 TPast"></tr>, <tr class="TRow2"></tr>]
```

Comment: Never occurred to me to look to CSS selectors for this.  Thanks, this did the trick.

Ended up needing to filter out 2 classes, but was able to just chain the :not selectors and it worked like a charm.